# how to collect radio button value during pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I've been working on a small project lately that involves question and answer. So basically it's a quiz/test, whatever you call this page. I made a database as per requirement for all the questions and answers storage. So yea, the output is coming from a database. Now, I need to output 5 questions at a time in a page so used pagination to do it.

```
$outputList = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){

  $question = $row['questions'];
  $opta = $row['optA'];
  $optb = $row['optB'];
  $optc = $row['optC'];
  $optd = $row['optD'];
  $id = $row['ctrlNo'];
  $outputList .="            
                <p>$id. $question</p>

                <div>

                    <input type='radio' name='question-$id-' id='question-$id-answers-A' value='A' />
                    <label for='question-$id-answers-A'>A) $opta </label>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-$id-' id='question-$id-answers-B' value='B' />
                    <label for='question-$id-answers-B'>B) $optb </label>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-$id-' id='question-$id-answers-C' value='C' />
                    <label for='question-$id-answers-C'>C) $optc </label>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-$id-' id='question-$id-answers-D' value='D' />
                    <label for='question-$id-answers-D'>D) $optd </label>
                </div>
            ";

}
```

Okay, so I have 4 radio buttons for the choices of each question and they are all working perfectly. What I can't figure out is collecting their values during pagination. I mean, when I'm on page 1 and submit my answers it's working, but when I go to page 2 and submit my answers it doesn't pass the values collected from page 1. Now I'm running out of ideas how to do it. Can anyone guide me as to what I can possibly do to gather all the values of the selected radio button first from page 1 to the current page of the user and pass it to my php page, which verifies the answers? Here's the code in my html.

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" action="testpage5.php" method="POST" >

 <?php print "$outputList"; ?>

 <p><div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-     color:#FFF; ">
 <?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?>
 </div></p>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz"></input>
 </form>`
```

`testpage5.php` is the page where I verify the answers comparing value of `$_POST` to the correct answer from the database. I used `$_POST` to collect the values of the radio buttons.

Comment: thank you Voitcus for editing my post. i'm new here and don't know exactly what commands to use to make those codes presentable as possible. hehehe :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `$_SESSION`. It's a super global array which stores values of a browser session.

An alternative is creating hidden form elements which contain the values of the previously submitted pages.

Comment: i tried $_SESSION but doesn't seem to work. it has the same output with $_POST. doesn't collect all the values. it only pass those that are on the current page.

Comment: Did you try to write a copy of your `POST`-Data in `$_SESSION`? It looks like you are not familiar with the concept of user sessions. Maybe you should read the corresponding section of php.net

Comment: hi Joshua! i have tried to use $_SESSION to fetch the value of a radio button with no success. maybe i was not doing the right thing then. on my testpage5.php the page where i verify the users answer i tried to match the database answer to the $_SESSION['radio-name'] as that's what i'm doing with $_POST[] where it returns a correct answer. however, in $_SESSION[] i don't get any value. can you show me how?